# Need to create one typology rule in adobe campaign

Tags: adobe-campaign-classic

In adobe campaign, I need to create a typology rule where that rule exlclude all the email address containing interger at the END of the address in the delivery ( target population ) ?

Example : xyz@gmail.com1 , abc@yahoo.com2 , zxc@hotmail.com99

Trying to get some insights on the typology how to create it, as it's bit new for me